# iTextSharp - Digital Signature Issue on Pdf File

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp to add digital signature to a new pdf. The digital signature is placed on the file as expected. However, when i click in the box its not actually allowing me to select my digital signature to sign with.

I have opened one of our companies other pdf files, that allows digital signature, just to test that my signature is working. When i click in the box in this pdf, it allows me to choose digital signature; so i know my signature does work.

Anyone know what causes this issue? The code to add the signature to the pdf, i am using for testing, is below:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\test.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("A paragraph"));
            PdfFormField sig = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(writer);
            sig.SetWidget(new Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), null);
            sig.FieldName = "testSignature";
            sig.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
            sig.SetPage();
            sig.MKBorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
            sig.MKBackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
            PdfAppearance appearance = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(writer, 72, 48);
            appearance.Rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 71.5f, 47.5f);
            appearance.Stroke();
            sig.SetAppearance(
              PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, appearance
            );
            writer.AddAnnotation(sig);
        }
```

Comment: Using the exact code that you posted and iTextSharp 5.4.0 the signature field appeared for me and allowed me to select a signature and sign the document. Can you post the PDF somewhere that we can inspect it?

Comment: question after further research. do I need to have adobe pro installed, to allow me to enable extended features?

Comment: please show by example what you mean.

Comment: added pdf file [link](http://www.programmingenigmas.com/test.pdf) that is created when i use the above code.. I currently, only have pdf reader. So i was curious if adobe pro is required to make signatures on the pdf page active. As i was reading around and saw posts stating something close to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding here.

When you add a signature field to a PDF using iText or iTextSharp, people who have the full version of Adobe Acrobat can use that field to sign a PDF. Or, you can use iText(Sharp) to sign the document programmatically.

People who only have Adobe Reader won't be able to sign the file by clicking the annotation. This is normal: the PDF isn't "Reader-enabled." Reader-enabling can only be done in Acrobat (and some other Adobe products). Using Adobe's private key, a special "usage rights" signature is applied. When Adobe Reader can validate this special signature using Adobe's public key, Adobe Reader unlocks specific functionality, such as: the ability to sign a document as if Reader was Acrobat.

It goes without saying that NO THIRD PARTY OTHER THAN ADOBE is allowed to use Adobe's private key to achieve this.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you. After reading more around, thats what it sounded like. Just wanted to verify and your answer helped.